# How to express Combination of two Adjectives with two Noun (element-wise)？

Tags: adjective

I know the title is very unreadable, so I give an example here.

**Case 1:**

- adj. rot und blau
- n. Hund

We say: der rote und der blaue Hund (zwei Hunde)

**Case 2:**

- adj. rot und blau
- n. Hund und Katze

So there are 4 combinations:

Roter Hund, rote Katze, blauer Hund, blaue Katze.

So how to express this "element-wise" relation ?

e.g. rot und blau __ Katze und Hund

**Why do I need this?**

e.g. figure 1 has a name, "globales und lokales Minimum"
[image]

Now in figure 2 there are "globales Minimum", "globales Maximum", "lokales Minimum", "lokales Maximum", how can I name for this figure:
[image]

Comment: "lokale/globale Maxima/Minima" or "lokale und globale Minima und Maxima"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear there are only approximate solutions for this.

1. One option is to use plural, which sidesteps the issue that it is "der Hund" but "die Katze", but doesn't convey that we have two dogs (red and blue) and two cats (red and blue) in total:

   > die roten und blauen Katzen und Hunde

   This would certainly work in a situation where the cats and dogs have been previously introduced, say:

   > Er sah einen roten Hund, eine rote Katze, einen blauen Hund und eine blaue Katze. Die roten und blauen Katzen und Hunde liefen weg.

   Note that technically, this could be misunderstood as "die (roten und blauen Katzen) und Hunde" instead of the intended "die (roten und blauen) (Katzen und Hunde)".
2. To be more precise about how many dogs and cats we are seeing, some construction with "je" might work. Unfortunately, here we run into trouble with "der Hund" vs. "die Katze". The following would work:

   > Je ein blauer und roter Hund und Kater
   >
   > Je eine blaue und rote Hündin und Katze

   But for "Katze und Hund" we have to rephrase a bit, for example:

   > Je ein Hund und eine Katze in blau und rot
3. If we are willing to rephase a bit more, we can look for a noun that includes dogs and cats, for example:

   > Zwei Katzen und zwei Hunde, je ein rotes und ein blaues Tier

   A similar trick might also work for your graph:

   > Gobale und lokale Extremwerte

Answer (score 3):

With dogs and cats you would say

> rote und blaue Hunde und Katzen

With your curves you would say

> Hier sehen Sie lokale und globale Minima und Maxima in einer Kurve vereint.

Note: don't say *lokale und globale Minimümmer und Maximümmer*. These are not correct plural forms although you may hear them in sloppy everyday conversations.

Comment: I never heard them. Minimums und Maximums, ja.

Comment: @userunknown  The big question is, would they be written with single m or with double m...

Comment: Die werden überhaupt nicht geschrieben, sondern nur gesprochen. Gut - jetzt muss man ein wortgetreues Transkript erstellen - was dann? Ein Minimum wird ja wie zwei Minimums betont und kommt auch mit einem Konsonanten aus, während bei den -mums immerhin ein kleines S assistiert (assistieren tut). Also single M.

Answer (score 0):

If we say

> Die beiden Hunde und Katzen

most people would assume that there are two dogs and two cats. Therefore your case could result in:

> - Die beiden Hunde und Katzen, jeweils rot und blau
> - Die beiden Minima und Maxima, jeweils lokal und global